# url.Actionlink to another website to index.php

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

How can I convert this ;

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Chat" , new { Id = item.Id , Member = item.Member }))" class="theme-btn btn-style-one hvr-bounce-to-right"><span style="float:right;min-width:210px;"></span>GİRİŞ</a><br /><br />
```

to be able to send Ids to index.php page in another ftp. which is (www.trp.com/index.php)

Comment: Are you trying to resolve an external url? Like www.trp.com/index.php?id=10&Member=john

Comment: Yes I am trying to send that to external url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not resolve an external url with `Url helper`. You cna just use `String.Format`

```
href="@String.Format("http://www.trp.com/index.php?id={0}&member={1}", item.Id, item.Member)"
```

Comment: it becomes this ; http://localhost:2088/Project/detail/www.trp.com/index.php?id=%2224%22&member=%222%22